# How to get this div onto a new line

Tags: html, css

How do I get ARC onto its own line?  I put them both in the same div to share a background, but I am having trouble separating the two.  My menu bar is perfectly centered until I put in "ARC".

```css
.header{
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/204495/pexels-photo-204495.jpeg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}


.header ul li{
float: left;
color: white;
list-style: none;
padding: 7px 6px;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
font-size: 15px;
display: flex;
}

.menu{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Services</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      <div class="title">
        <h1>ARC</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the HTML
from this:

```
 <div class="header">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Services</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      <div class="title">
        <h1>ARC</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

To this (solution):

```
 <div class="header">
    <div id="navbar-wrapper">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Services</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      <div class="title">
        <h1>ARC</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Conclusion: it is better to use for example a div tag to make a new line than br tag as you gain much more control over your page setup and it is easier to style. 
Keep on good work!

Answer (score 1):

Since your `li` is float left they will be one next to the other.

add clear:left to the element and it will work.

```
.header ul li{
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    ...
 }
```

---

#### **`clear`**

> The **`clear`** CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to **floating** elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them.
>
> The clear property applies to both floating and non-floating elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just applied some of the CSS styles to only the links and that worked. Hope this helps!

```css
.header{
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/204495/pexels-photo-204495.jpeg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100%;
}


.header ul li{
float: left;
color: white;
list-style: none;
padding: 7px 6px;
margin: 0;
font-size: 15px;
}

.menu{
text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Services</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      <div class="title">
        <h1>ARC</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```